# Formatting Pandas decimals in Django

Tags: python, django, pandas

I´m not able to format some numbers with fixed decimal positions on Pandas dataframe in Django.

I´ve tryied several options:

```
round(testdataframe["ticket_medio"], 1)
```

Result: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'

```
np.round(testdataframe["ticket_medio"], decimals=1)
```

Result: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'

```
testdataframe.round(1)
```

Result: nothing seems to happen

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.1f}'.format
testdataframe.round(1)
```

Result: nothing seems to happen

Comment: The error doesn't have anything to do with decimal points. Both data types must be the same, either decimal or float. I guess converting `ticket_medio` to numeric should fix the issue: `testdataframe['ticket_medio'] = pd.to_numeric(testdataframe['ticket_medio'])`

Comment: Thanks @Borut, that helped and now I can round the number to my desired decimals with `testdataframe['ticket_medio'] = testdataframe.ticket_medio.round(0)` but when I see the number in the template I still have 1 decimal point (althaough it´s 0 because I rounded up to 0). Like **2250.0**

Comment: In the template you can use [floatformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) filiter to round numbers, eg: `{{ number|floatformat:"0" }}`

Comment: Thanks @Borut I´ll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Borut explained, the solution was first to change my Pndas dataframe values to numeric:

```
testdataframe['ticket_medio'] = pd.to_numeric(testdataframe['ticket_medio'])
```

Then, in the template you should use `{{ your_value|floatformat:"0" }}` to actualy showing the number with your desired decimal points.